# Find Parent Control's Server-Side element from userControl by jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, user-controls, find, parent-child

I have an asp.net page(*page1.aspx*) which use One UserControl(*UC1.ascx*).

While changing textBox in userControl, I want to fill a *textBox in page1.aspx*.

Is there any jQuery or JavaScript Function for that?
How can I get access to parent page's element?

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Whenever your page is rendered there is just html output; no parent-page/usercontrol. So, you always have access in js.

Comment: @mshsayem : but should I set the masterpage's textBox through Usercontrol? If yes, then the masterpage's textBox ( $('#<% =txtSearch.ClientID %>') )  is not known in UserControl . how can I get access to it?

Answer (score 0):

Usercontrol should have no knowledge of it's parent aspx. It is the main aspx who should decide what to do. So you can expose your usercontrol's textbox (or it's ClientID) as a public property, then attach js method to do the rest.

Example:

**MyUserControl.ascx:**

```
...

<asp:TextBox id="ucTextBox" runat="server" />

...
```

**MyUserControl.ascx.cs:**

```
...

public TextBox ChanginTextBox
{
    get
    {
        return ucTextBox;
    }
}

...
```

**MainAspx:**

```
...

<uc:MyUserControl Id="myUC" runat="server" />

...
<script>
$(function(){
    // jQuery
    $("#<%=myUC.ChanginTextBox.ClientID %>").on("change",function(){
        // fill your other text box
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Actually, what I want is a bit different. I mean I need to get access to parent through UserControl . Is there any way for that also?
I use your code in a test page, but change event is not fired. should I add something for binding it or else  in **Usercontrol serverside** or **client side**??

Comment: The change event is not fired because I haven't call it in document.ready. Edited.

Comment: You can access parent page's control by `this.Page.FindControl()`. But it will be bad as it uses string. If somehow id of your desired control is renamed or somehow removed you will encounter a run-time error.